# Python socket.io - how to connect over HTTPS?

Tags: python, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to send socket.io message to a nodejs server over HTTPS. After googling around for the socketIO on Python; I have written the below simple code to make a test.
Although I receive no compile error, I receive nothing from the server. When I analyzed via wireshark packetsniffer; I noticed that HTTPS connection is not even established (target server has the valid signed certificate and I can access the server via JS based frontend without any problem)..

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace
NODEJS_URL = "https://targetserver.com"

def on_message_response(*args):
    print('message', args)

user_value = "test1"
message_value = "hello"

with SocketIO(NODEJS_URL, 443, LoggingNamespace) as socketIO:
    socketIO.emit('message', { 'user': user_value, 'message': message_value}, on_message_response)
    socketIO.wait_for_callbacks(seconds=1)
```

Do you have any idea why Python socketIO connection might not be successful?